# Flaw with Knuth original attribute grammar paper

Tags: attribute-grammars

[Knuth's original attribute grammar paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.455.1434) (title: *Semantics of Context-Free Languages*) apparently had a flaw where circularity is always detected but
some noncircular AGs may be reported to be circular. Knuth later constructed
an exact algorithm which is exponential in time. I am wondering what was the fix? which part of the algorithm was the source of the problem?